# Incorrect number of likes showing in Facebook like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I would like to present some youtube videos on my website along with like buttons setted to their urls.

According to documentation there should be number of total likes/shares etc. However I discovered that sometimes Like button is not working correctly - shows "0 likes" when video has thousands of shares.

Example:

URL : youtube.com/watch?v=JVGAfA15U1I

Like button shows 0 likes (you can check it here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ )

On the other hand
https://graph.facebook.com/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DJVGAfA15U1I
shows that this video has 46000+ shares

What can be done to fix this problem?

EDIT:

I found that graph query for some videos likes looks like:

```
{
"id": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVGAfA15U1I",    "shares":
46338
}
```

and for another:

```
{
   "id": "165846656805072",
   "name": "Lady Gaga - Bad Romance",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/162003_165846656805072_1555282555_s.jpg",
   "link": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrO4YZeyl0I",
   "likes": 5645,
   "app_id": 87741124305,
   "category": "Video",
   "is_published": true,
   "website": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrO4YZeyl0I",
   "description": "Music video by Lady Gaga performing Bad Romance. (C) 2009 Interscope Records",
   "about": "Music video by Lady Gaga performing Bad Romance. (C) 2009 Interscope Records",
   "can_post": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are just confusing different counters.

If you look at the [link_stat fql table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/) you'll notice 5 different counters:

- likes count
- shares count
- comments count
- total count (likes + shares + comments)
- clicks count

In the link you posted (2nd one, to the graph object) you'll see just the *shares*, there are no likes there. How ever if you try the same thing with the [Like Plugin](https://graph.facebook.com/http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) page, you'll see likes but no shares.

The like plugin just shows you the likes counter, not the other ones (so it seems).

Comment: According to like button documentation "The number shown is the sum of the number of likes of this URL, the number of shares of this URL (this includes copy/pasting a link back to Facebook), The number of likes and comments on stories on Facebook about this URL, The number of inbox messages containing this URL as an attachment.
"

Comment: True. Have you came across more examples in which this happens, or just this video?

Comment: Yes, there are many other examples, I just checked this one http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lpj3dy9ALQ0 . However I only tested YouTube links, so there is possibility that other domains can be afftected by this problem too.

Comment: According to this [fql query](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20url%2C%20normalized_url%2C%20share_count%2C%20like_count%2C%20comment_count%2C%20total_count%2C%20commentsbox_count%2C%20comments_fbid%2C%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url%3D%22http%253A%252F%252Fwww.youtube.com%252Fwatch%253Fv%253DJVGAfA15U1I%22) you are right, maybe try to [file a bug report](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create).

Comment: Do you really think it's a bug? I'm not so sure. And I discovered something - check my updated question.

Comment: Well, if you check the source of both videos you'll see that the og meta tags are exactly the same in both (except for the video values). That means that there's an inconsistency in the data, good chance that it's a bug I think, open one and see what they tell you